# how to provide argument as Union?

Tags: python

Disclaimer: I don't have any Idea about c language

I am trying to make this thing work:

https://github.com/berdario/resumable-urlretrieve

here is the function:

```
path = Union[str, Path]
urlretrieve(url: str, filename: path, reporthook=None, method='GET',
                sha256sum=None, filesize=None, headers=None,
                **kwargs) -> Dict[str, str]:
```

How should I provide the filename?
I am seeing for the first time colon in the argument.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: This has nothing to do with C and everything with [type hints](/questions/32557920/what-are-type-hints-in-python-3-5). Read it as `urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook = False,` etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Union` here has nothing to do with C or the kind of unions found in C. It just means that you can provide either a `str` or a `Path` for the `filename` argument... whatever a `Path` is in this context.

Comment: What is the advantage of using this programming style?

Comment: You know that you can give that function either a string or a path. Generally if you see a function you have no idea what arguments it takes, so the typing library (and [syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)) gives you some possibilities to give some information there. If you want to say "give me either a string or a path, but nothing else" `Union` is the thing to do that.

Comment: @syntonym, and how I use the argument, each type has different set of methods ?